How do I calculate the output voltage of this circuit with a diode?

I need to calculate the range of the output voltage Vo for the range -5<=Vi<=5. The diode is silicon.  It's all fine when Vi is 2V and below because then the diode won't conduct.  But, I don't know what happens when it starts to conduct. Since the circuit here is just a junction, it confuses me. Can someone help me solve this?

Do you want a closed solution using the Shockley equation? Or is your diode some kind of ideal type? The math is a little tricky if you want something close to reality. Otherwise, if you don't care about that, it can be very easy.

@periblepsis That wasn't specified in the question but since it said it was a silicone diode I'm guessing that it's the practical model. 0.7 V when conducting and no voltage leaking when reverse polarized. I don't know the shockley equation.

Okay. Then it is very simple. If $v_i\lt +2.7:\text{V}$ the diode is off and $v_o=v_i$. If $v_i\ge +2.7:\text{V}$ the diode is on and $v_o=+2.7:\text{V}$. (If you were discussing real parts and cared about the details more then the algebra gets tricky.)

@periblepsis Thanks for clearing that up for me I used some AI tools and they confused me more than they helped. Thank you for helping.

@periblepsis - Hi, Thanks as always for helping. However please remember not to answer in a comment, as that is not an allowed use of comments. Answering in comments can also be harmful to the site so we really want to avoid that. Is there something I can help with, which is preventing you posting that as an answer?

@MertSığınmış Note that silicon and silicone are two very different things.

@SamGibson It appears that lying AI's are an issue with this author. So perhaps the comment can be considered nothing more than uncovering this issue for the OP and not really as an answer. At this point deleting it might make the author's following comment lose its context. (Though I initially considered removing it based on your own comment, I'm now -- upon reading the author's addition -- inclined at this time to keep it here.) You, of course, have your own larger views and I will respect any choices you make.

@MertSığınmış You should never use any AI at this time for anything of a technical or numerical nature. Even the slightest changes, removing or adding any specific detail at all, leads to radically different results from the more readily available AI bots, at this time. They lie convincingly, as though they know something. And if you try and nail them down in areas where you know your cases well, you will find them completely incompetent while sounding firm, authoritative, and confident.

May I suggest you use the simulator and see if the shape of the graphs helps you understand how to calculate it?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I did that but I need to do it on paper. I am a little bit new to circuit analysis with diodes. Can I ask you what are those triangles in the circuit diagram? Is that the symbol of ground and does it mean that the negative terminals of the voltage sources are connected?

Yes, the triangles are ground; it's usually the case (especially in academic circuits for analysis) that everything is connected to some common reference but they don't tell you this.  You'd expect the diode to conduct when it is forward biased.  Thus V1 has to be > V2 + 0.7 (being rule-of-thumb value for Vf of a silicon diode).  And the higher V1 is, the more the diode will conduct.

Thanks for cralifying. That was the main reason why I was confused. Thanks for the answer.
